# unable to install git from source code

Tags: linux, git, bash, ubuntu, github

I am new to using git. So i first install git from terminal using apt-get but then i remove it as in ubuntu the version is very old.

After this i install git from source code which i download from https://code.google.com/p/git-core/downloads/list. Then these are the commands used by me

`sudo apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev libexpat1-dev gettext libz-dev libssl-dev build-essential`

`tar -zxf git-1.9.0.tar.gz`

`cd git-1.9.0/`

`make prefix=/usr/local all`

`sudo make prefix=/usr/local install`

Then when i put these commands it is behaving in this manner.

**~/git-1.9.0$ which git**

**/usr/local/bin/git**

**~/git-1.9.0$ git --version**

**bash: /usr/bin/git: No such file or directory**

Comment: what are the results of `echo $PATH`?

Comment: /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games

Comment: Show exactly -by editing your question- how did you *configure* and *build* your `git`

Comment: You need to do `make configure` then to run `configure`  appropriately.

Comment: Does `hash -d git; git --version` work?

Comment: `hash -d git; git --version` is returning the version of git. It is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your shell remembers where it found the executable file for commands you run, to save itself the trouble (and you the delays) of hunting them down repeatedly.  `which` isn't a bash builtin, so it doesn't know about that.  When you've installed new code it's rarely a bad idea to

```
 $ hash -r    # reset the command-lookup hashtable
```

or if you've got just one particular command in mind,

> `$ hash -d`*`command`*`# forget where`*`command`*`came from`

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add `/usr/local/bin/` to your `$PATH`, perhaps in `~/.bashrc`; you might want to put it before `/usr/bin/` there.

And you could simply type the entire path of the binary, e.g.

```
/usr/local/bin/git --version
```

or

```
/usr/local/bin/git status
```

<sup>You might try to use `strace` to understand what is going on.</sup>

Did you read *git* [INSTALL](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/INSTALL) file? You probably want to go the `autoconf` way (e.g. `make configure` first, then `configure` with appropriate arguments....) and you surely need to give relevant arguments at `configure` time, in particular `--exec-prefix=` and/or `--libexecdir=` ....

Comment: `/usr/local/bin` is already in `$PATH` and by typing the entire path of the binary i am getting the version number but other commands are not running  e.g.
`git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/git/git.git`

It is still giving the same error.

Comment: `/usr/local/bin/status` is giving this :

**fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git**